# Notice : URL timeout: DNS lookup timeout when test sitemap in Google search Console

Tags: dns, sitemap, google-search-console

How to solve `URL timeout: DNS lookup timeout` error when testing sitemap file in Google Search Console?

I generated my sitemap file in [www.xml-sitemaps.com](https://www.xml-sitemaps.com/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Google can't access your sitemap.xml.
Can you open url of your sitemap.xml in your browser?
Make sure there is no errors in url, especially in domain name.